# Wifi wont work or even show up in E Os. No matter what!

Tags: wifi

People I have tried everything and have mucked up the E Os installs three times based on these forums. Nothing personal but my other linux builds work fine with no problems. I thought EOS was a stronger build but that is yet to be determined. The ethernet shows up but no matter how many times I update the drivers or update the kernel. WIFI simply doesn't show up on this Lenovo desktop tower. I would really really appreciate any help before I slap give up and dump this build...

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with your hardware specifications (Which desktop/laptop, exactly hardware components, etc.)

Also provide us the output of `sudo lshw`, most important here would be `sudo lshw -C network`.

Which version of eOS are you using?
Have you done the updates? (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y && sudo apt-get autoclean -y` or similar)

Comment: LenovoAMD A9-9425 Radeon R5

Comment: LenovoAMD A9-9425 Radeon R5, 5 Compute Cores 2C+3G 3.10GHz. RAM 4 G. 64-bit, Windows 10 & Elementary OS 5.0 Juno, Realtek 8821CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC. I also ran those updates you mentioned and received only one error. But still nothing... I really hopes this helps. I know Debian will work but I really want E OS to work...

Comment: *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea0ffff

Comment: So it is an known issue with RTL8821CE Network controller. In my opinion you have two possibilities:
1) Try the way descripte in https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
2) Try to download driver from https://github.com/alanfox2000/realtek-linux/tree/master/RTL8821CE

Both options seems to work, I would start with option 2. Inside the zip files there is an install.sh, so just execute it with sudo priviliges. I am not able to check it, because I do not have this network controller.